# Drop down button in flutter: value isn't compiling

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this drop down button in flutter:

```
DropdownButton(

value: _value,
    items: [
      DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text("First Item"),
        value: 1,
      ),
      DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text("Second Item"),
        value: 2,
      ),
      DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text("Third Item"),
          value: 3
      ),
      DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text("Fourth Item"),
          value: 4
      )
    ],
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
        _value = value; //here I get the error
      });
    })
```

I get the following error: `A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.`

On the following line: `_value = value;`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The error basically means that your `_value` variable does not have the `int` type. Post your entire code file, I can help you out.

Comment: @NisanthReddy That's incorrect. `_value` already has the `int` type.

Comment: @NisanthReddy I am not the OP. I'm saying your analysis is incorrect.

Comment: My bad, didnt see the user name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the type of `value` with the generic on the `DropdownButton` constructor:

```dart
DropdownButton<int>(
...
```

The way you currently have it, the `DropdownButton` does not know what type `value` is supposed to be, so the `onChanged` callback provides the most generic type, an `Object?`. Adding the generic parameter tells the button that it should expect and emit `int` values.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it and now I get this error: A value of type 'int?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.

Comment: do `_value = value!;` instead of `_value = value;` or make `_value` nullable.

Comment: it worked thanks! Can you explain it please?

Comment: @Sam12 Which part?

Comment: what does this token '!' do?

Comment: @Sam12 `value` is nullable. It has the type `int?`. But `_value` is an `int`. So if `value` is `null` and you assign it to `_value`, you're violating null safety. The `!` operator is the bang operator. It tells the compiler "I know that `value` will not be null. Stop complaining.". We know that `value` can never be `null` because none of your menu items have a value of `null`, but it's generally better to make `_value` nullable.

Comment: @Sam12 You can read more about null safety [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).